# regex help, replace all occurrences of words from 1 array with 'xxx' in another array containing phrases and remove additional occurrences of 'xxx'

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

So this is where I'm at, I have an array of keywords lets say $keywords =

```
$keywords = array('abc','xyz','asd')
```

then a list of phrases

```
$phrases = array('this is abc', 'xyz this is abc', 'thisxyz is xyz', 'this is abcxyz', 'xyzthis is abc');
```

I have done a simple

```
$array = str_replace($keywords, 'xxx', $phrases);
```

I end up with

```
array('this is xxx', 'xxx this is xxx', 'thisxxx is xxx', 'this is xxxxxx', 'xxxthis is xxx');
```

Now I need to remove all occurrences of 'xxx' where if falls within a word e.g. xxxthisis, thisxxx, with just 'xxx'. I have tried

```
preg_replace('/xxx[a-zA-Z0-9]+/', 'xxx', $phrase);
```

but this will only take care of 'thisxxx' and replace it with xxx. I need it to replace all occurrences of xxx where it fall in a word and replace the whole word with xxx

Finally, I need to remove multiple occurrences of xxx from each phrase and leave only one I am doing

```
substr_replace($phrase,'',  strpos($phrase, 'xxx')+3);
```

Long story short, I need help with the regex for the middle step but also thinking if this is all possible in less then 3 steps with just 1 regex or with sql as both are in DB as 2 different columns in two tables.

Comment: You can use `\b` to find word boundaries, so `\b.*xxx.*\b` should give you the right matches (in non-greedy mode).

Comment: but wouldn't that take the whole phrase, i tried it in regexp helper and it matches the whole phrase not just the word containing the phrase

Comment: That's why you need non-greedy mode. In PHP you can do `.*?` to make it non-greedy.

Comment: Tried \b.*?xxx.*?\b it captures whole phrase/string

Answer (score 1):

You can use one preg_replace call to replace with xxx and another to remove replicated xxx:

```
$phrases = array('this is abc', 'xyz this is abc', 'thisxyz is xyz', 'this is abcxyz', 'xyzthis is abc');
$r = preg_replace('/\S*(?:abc|xyz|asd)\S*/', 'xxx', $phrases);
$r = preg_replace('/((?<=xxx).*)xxx/', '$1', $r);
print_r($r)
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => this is xxx
    [1] => xxx this is 
    [2] => xxx is 
    [3] => this is xxx
    [4] => xxx is 
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but now i face the final problem, to replace multiple instances of 'xxx' in a string with just 1. so 'xxx is xxx' becomes 'xxx is' and 'xxx this is xxx' becomes 'xxx this is'

Comment: I have a long winded method in mind to find first occurrence of xxx and break it apart using substr then in remaining string replace all 'xxx' with '' then join them back but looking for a more optimized way to do this as the script would be processing a million rows.

Comment: Ok, i didn't understood this requirement at first. Updated the code, please check

Answer (score 0):

You should be performing both rounds of replacements in a single call.  You can accomplish this feat by matching whole words that "are" or "contain" a keyword.  By building a single pipe-delimited list of keywords inside of a non-capturing group, then extending the leading and trailing keyword-group to also match letters, you can replace all of your intended strings in a single go.

If you are making a robust/dynamic solution, then you should incorporate case-insenstive matching and prepare each keyword with `preg_quote()` to escape any characters with special meaning to the regex engine.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qrlLO))

```
$keywords = array('abc', 'xyz', 'spec!^lchar.*', 'asd');
print_r($keywords);
$keywords = array_map(function($v){return preg_quote($v, '/');}, $keywords);
print_r($keywords);
$phrases = array('this is abc', 'xyz this is abc', 'thisxyz is xyz', 'this is abcxyz', 'xyzthis is abc');

// \w means [A-Za-z0-9_]
var_export(preg_replace('/[a-z]*(?:' . implode('|', $keywords) . ')[a-z]*/i', 'xxx', $phrases));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => xyz
    [2] => spec!^lchar.*
    [3] => asd
)
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => xyz
    [2] => spec\!\^lchar\.\*
    [3] => asd
)
array (
  0 => 'this is xxx',
  1 => 'xxx this is xxx',
  2 => 'xxx is xxx',
  3 => 'this is xxx',
  4 => 'xxx is xxx',
)
```

See? All tasks completed in a single replacement call -- direct and professional.

Answer (score -1):

You should use negative look-around's: `(?<!\b)xxx|xxx(?!\b)`